# Splitting a range into min and max?

Tags: ruby

I needed to get the minimum and maximum date values from a query using the Sequel ORM in Ruby from my database. Sequel has a `range` method that returns a Range value. I'm having it return values from a timestamp field, so they're coming back as a range of Time objects.

In order to split it into two variables using parallel assignment, I figured this was about as concise and succinct as I could get:

```
template_min_datestamp, template_max_datestamp = [Template.range(:created_at)].map{ |r| [r.min, r.max] }
```

I considered using:

```
template_min_datestamp, template_max_datestamp = Template.min(:created_at), Template.max(:created_at)
```

but that'd cause two hits to the database, which just makes my eye twitch.

Simplifying it for the innocent, and factoring out the ORM calls, it'd look something like this in regular Ruby:

```
t1 = Time.parse('Jan 1, 2013 12:00:00 -700')
t2 = Time.parse('Jan 31, 2013 12:00:00 -700')
template_min_datestamp, template_max_datestamp = [t1..t2].map{ |r| [r.min, r.max] }
```

It seems like there'd be a more direct way to break apart a range into two elements on one line using parallel assignment, but it's escaping me right now.

Anyone got some enlightenment to share?

Comment: `template_min_datestamp, template_max_datestamp = [t1..t2].map{ |r| [r.min, r.max] }[0]` this works, but I'm not sure if it is what you want.

Comment: @YuriyGolobokov: yup, that's also what I understood.  But then again, although `map` + `first` works, it seems a very non-declarative workaround of the abstraction as/into/chain/...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

@steenslag points out the `minmax` builtin. No monkey patching necessary.

```
template_min_datestamp, template_max_datestamp = Template.range(:created_at).minmax
```

Comment: `(2..6).minmax #=>[2, 6]`  is plain Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need a `let`-abstraction, for example [Object#as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848967/) (or whatever name you like for it, it seems to have dozens). I'd write:

```
# this goes in your core_ext module.
class Object
  def as
    yield self
  end
end

t1 = Time.parse('Jan 1, 2013 12:00:00 -700')
t2 = Time.parse('Jan 31, 2013 12:00:00 -700')
min_datestamp, max_datestamp = (t1..t2).as { |r| [r.min, r.max] }
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but that's taken one line of code to seven and hasn't really simplified anything, it's just blurred what is happening. I'm going to go poke at the `*` operator with `..` and see if there's some undiscovered magic there.

Comment: `Object#as` is a generic method, an abstraction that you won't write there. As I see it this effectively reduces the code to one quite descriptive line: `min_datestamp, max_datestamp = (t1..t2).as { |r| [r.min, r.max] }`. If vanilla Ruby does not provide an abstraction you need, you write it. "blurred what is happening". This is a archetypical let-block used in lots of languages (and used by many Ruby developers), nothing fancy. Or maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. I edited the question. Hopefully it'll be more clear. I'm trying to avoid making dual DB requests, and make use of the `min` and `max` ends of the range that's returned, without resorting to embedding the range inside `[]` and using `map`. I can't decide if that's a skanky hack, or a brilliant use of `map`.